# jackrabbit webdav disable?

Tags: webdav, jackrabbit, clickjacking, nessus

recently my jackrabbit(2.8.0) has been scanned by nessue with 2 issue

one is some jsp page has clickjacking (please see[jackrabbit webdav use HTTP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6zeG.gif))

and the other is use http instead of https (please see [some jackrabbit's jsp page have cickjacking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABHre.gif))

try to google but no luck ( or maybe I use wrong keyword),
is these 2 issue can be mitigated or workaround ?

or , can webdav be simply disabled?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. Instead [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The "HTTP" issue can easily be mitigated by turning off HTTP.
2. The other issue is a non-issue.

General advice: install available updates; you are several years behind the current version.

Comment: I just take over this system no long, but I will try to convince develop team to use latest version